# How to get the list of all the printers installed/connected printers in Node.Js

Tags: node.js, electron

I am creating a desktop application in Node.Js using Electron framework and want to get the list of all the printers installed/connected in Node.Js.
I had **already tried node-printer** but it is not installing properly.

Comment: are you on windows , because `node-printer` build is failing https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer

Comment: yes i am on windows

Comment: are there any other libraries for the same

Comment: you can check `electron-printer` https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-printer

Answer (score 4):

```
 const { exec } = require('child_process');
  exec('wmic printer list brief', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
  }
  // list of printers with brief details
  console.log(stdout);
  // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
  stdout=stdout.split("  ");
  var printers=[];
  j=0;
  stdout = stdout.filter(item => item);
  for (i = 0; i < stdout.length; i++)
  {
    if(stdout[i]==" \r\r\n" ||stdout[i]=="\r\r\n")
    {
       printers[j]=stdout[i+1];
       j++; 
    }
  }
  // list of only printers name
  console.log(printers);
  console.log(stderr);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's quite straightforward. You get the list of printers as given below

```js
window.webContents.getPrintersAsync().then((data) => {
    // data will be an array of printer objects
}).catch((e) => {
    // handle error here
})
```

which will return a promise. Previously `getPrinters()` method was in use but it's deprecated now. Refer to the [official docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsgetprintersasync)

Answer (score 0):

check this node package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/zuzel-printer

```
var Printer = require('zuzel-printer');
// Get available printers list
Printer.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you target Windows machines you could use `winreg` package to search the Registry for printers. All local printers can be found at

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | SYSTEM | CurrentControlSet | Control | Print | Printers`

, the network printers in

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | SYSTEM | CurrentControlSet | Control | Print | Providers | LanMan Print Services | servers | printers`

Answer (score 0):

If you target Windows machines you could use winreg package to search the Registry for printers. All local printers can be found at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | SYSTEM | CurrentControlSet | Control | Print | Printers
```

The network printers in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | SYSTEM | CurrentControlSet | Control | Print | Providers | LanMan Print Services | servers | printers
```